# Sort order for Answers by Votes and Oldest

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

If I choose to sort the answers by `Votes` there is no suborder if vote count is equal.

Wouldn't it be nice if the answers with the same vote count would also be ordered by `oldest`?

Comment: I think it's intentional, though I'd like that too. At least as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is intentionally random at the same vote level to help limit the [Fastest Gun in the West](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) problem. Randomly ordering posts ensures a fair, random evaluation of any two answers that have the same vote. Since people tend to read the first answer more often than the second (and so on), by not randomly ordering them, you're making it statistically less likely that the later answers will be voted on.

In addition, post time order rarely matters unless two posts are basically identical. We care about how *correct* the posts are, not how fast the poster was.